# Sample size and standard errors in OLS estimation

Tags: regression, inference, sample-size, standard-error

The standard errors of the estimated parameters from OLS estimation strongly depend on the sample size (n). Indeed, the standard errors tend to decrease when the sample size gets larger (ceteris paribus).

Given the above, my question is as follows: ***Why can't we use each observation twice or thrice, etc., so that the sample used in OLS estimation increases from n to 2n or 3n, etc.?***

For example, let us say that my original sample includes observations for 100 persons (i.e., n=100); moreover, for each person I know whether the person eats fast food daily (dummy variable), and I know the weight of the person. I want to study the effect of eating fast food daily on weight. Using this sample (n=100), I find that daily consumption of fast food does not *significantly* affect weight, because of the very large standard error. From a theoretical point of view, can I run a regression using a sample size n=200 (or n=300) in which case I repeat the data for each observation twice (or thrice)? Do you know any theoretical paper that has ever analyzed this problem?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use this approach with traditional regression, since one of the assumptions of OLS is independence of the error terms.  This assumption wouldn't be met in this case because drawing 1 unit would imply that you know the value of another unit in the sample (when $n = 200$) or 2 other units in the sample (when $n = 300$).  Besides, simply making an exact copy of the data and analyzing it, isn't providing any new information.  As an aside, bootstrapping can provide some interesting information.  Try searching on CV for "Bootrap" and you'll find something more interesting.

Comment: I would image that your errors suffer from heteroskedasticity (i.e. skinny people don't eat fast food, and some fat people eat fast food and others don't).  Boostrapping might help, but likely not much.  SE using boostraping is generally more efficient than their analytic counterparts.  However, if neither work, collecting data is really your only option.  Repeating observations, in the manner you mention, will never work.  Think about it, if I could repeat observations, then why not obtain a single observation and  repeat it a bunch of times.  Id never need to collect data!

Comment: @JacobH, more importantly, the errors would be correlated!!!

Comment: Yup. I did not dress this in my comment as you already pointed this out.  Taken that as given, the OP's best path going forward is to control for heteroskedasticity. Bootstrapping is likely to help much.

Comment: Why have I never thought of doing this? It is certainly very creative. Inspired by your approach and in quest of statistical significance, how about you subset your data leaving only individuals with extreme weight values at both ends (say bottom 20% and top 20% extreme weights). Then re-run the regression?